# Sass placeholders (%) not working with the latest version (3.2.1)

Tags: sass

I have the latest version of Sass (3.2.1 Media Mark) installed on a Mac OS X (10.7.4).

```
$ sass -v
Sass 3.2.1 (Media Mark)
```

When I'm trying to create a placeholder (for example)

```
#page-container {
  position: relative;
}

%sample {background: red;}

// The structure
@import 'header';
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule,
was "%sample {border..." on line 65 of 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/(project_path)/assets/scss/application.scss"
```

I thought that uninstalling and reinstalling Sass will solve the problem, but it didn't.
Is it something that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Post the context. (What code is above and below that line?)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm pretty sure that the syntax is correct :)

Comment: How exactly are you using the placeholder? What is line 65 of your code? If your syntax was correct, most likely you would not get that error...

Comment: Try putting the declaration on a separate line: `%sample { ↩ background: red; ↩ }` (where `↩` is a new line)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas that won't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Well, I've found the problem!**
I was using the [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) application that automatically watches the changes inside a folder/project. **I've reinstalled it and now it works.** It seems like the applications is using its own version of Sass (or something like this), which is a bit wierd!

Comment: A lot of similar applications like LiveReload bundle Sass and the like which can become quickly outdated

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted your terminal?  I had the same problem when I upgraded Sass.  I had upgraded Sass in a different terminal than the one that I was running my watch from, and I couldn't use the new Sass features from there.  I could use them from the terminal that I used to upgrade Sass with.

If you've closed and opened all of your terminals and it still doesn't work, try a reboot.